# Ajax edit ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Code not work if I change AJAXEditIsDoneCheckBox to Edit why is that? Code work fine without changing but I want to know the problem. I will be grateful for the answer.

**Controller**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AJAXEditIsDoneCheckBox(int? id, bool value)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    ToDo toDo = db.ToDos.Find(id);
    if (toDo == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    else
    {
        toDo.IsDone = value;
        db.Entry(toDo).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return PartialView("_ToDoTable", GetToDoes());
    }
}
```

**Script**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ActiveCheck').change(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        var id = self.attr('id');
        var value = self.prop('checked');

        $.ajax({

            url: '/ToDoes/EditIsDoneCheckBox',
            data: {
                id: id,
                value: value
            },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#tableDiv').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

View:

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsDone, new { id = item.Id, @class = "ActiveCheck" })
```

Comment: "Code not work "  - what part is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the name of the action in the controller from `AJAXEditIsDoneCheckBox` to `Edit`, then you must also update the URL in the ajax method:

```
// controller
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id, bool value)
{ 
    ...
}

// view
$.ajax({
    url: '/ToDoes/Edit',
    ...
}
```

I hope I've understood the problem, if not, please update your question.